# Why doesn't FancyBox window size adjust?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am using FancyBox 2 on this page: http://encoreazalea.com/ee/botanical-gardens to display Google Maps in a popup window.

The windows come up fine but all the maps have scrollbars. I have tried resizing the display window, but it doesn't seem to respond properly to the instructions I send.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h3 class="state">Washington D.C.</h3>

<div class="gardens">

<p class="garden">US National Arboretum<br />
<a href="http://www.usna.usda.gov/">Website</a> | <a class="map" href="#directions5148">Directions</a></p>
</div>

<div class="gardens">
<div id="directions5148" style="display:none">
<iframe width="600" height="440" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;q=US+National+Arboretum&amp;fb=1&amp;gl=us&amp;hq=US+National+Arboretum&amp;hnear=US+National+Arboretum&amp;cid=0,0,12451978746893569755&amp;t=h&amp;ll=38.912424,-76.96852&amp;spn=0.008014,0.013733&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;q=US+National+Arboretum&amp;fb=1&amp;gl=us&amp;hq=US+National+Arboretum&amp;hnear=US+National+Arboretum&amp;cid=0,0,12451978746893569755&amp;t=h&amp;ll=38.912424,-76.96852&amp;spn=0.008014,0.013733&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>

</div>

</p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".map").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            width : 700,
            height : 600,
            closeClick : true,
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background-color' : '#eee'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

No matter what I set the width and height at the window always displays at the same size and there are scroll bars around the map.

My goal is to get rid of the scrollbars.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was silly but fancybox was not responding properly because I had not included this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {...
```

After I added that the rest of the code became more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding dimensions direct to the div instead:

```
<div id="directions5148" class="map_window" style="display:none">
```

CSS:

```
.map_window{
   width: 700px;
   height: 600px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to set the options `autoSize : false` AND  `fitToView : false` AND `scrolling: "no"` to get the size you want.